# How to use filter query correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

i have this mongoose schema

```
const AddressSchema = new Schema({
    city : String,
    address : String,
    favorite : Boolean,
    description:String,
    lat : String,
    lng : String,
});

export const orderSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    require: [true, "EL id es necesario"],
    default: 0
  },
  newAddress : AddressSchema,
});
```

And im trying to do a search a record with the city param inside newAddress object, something like that

```
//ordersModel its the same Order Schema
const ActiveOrders = await this.ordersModel.find({newAddress:{city : city}});
```

but im getting this error

```
(property) newAddress?: Condition<Address>
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ city: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Condition<Address>'.
      Type '{ city: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Address': address, favorite, description, lat, lng
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know why you are getting an error, but if you want to find orders by city, you should change your query as mentioned below.

```
const ActiveOrders = await User.find({"newAddress.city" : city});
```